# Siebel MVG applet taking time to open

Tags: siebel

There is an Address MVG field on Contact record. While creating new record if I click on this address MVG field, MVG applets takes a lot of time to get open (20 min). Kindly help to fix this. Or let me know the possible fixs or ways to fix it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide more information to clarify your question. Which Siebel version do you use? What's your database (Oracle, MySQL...) and what version is it? Does the 20 minutes delay happen in all the environments (development, production, etc) on only in one of them?

Comment: Its Siebel version 8.0.1 and it is happening all environment, DB is oracle. Please let me know if you want more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first question that you should answer is: does it happen because of Siebel or the database?

To determine it, you can use a dedicated client with the SQL spool enabled, by adding the `/s` parameter to the command line in the shortcut. For example: `D:\Siebel\Client\BIN\siebel.exe /c D:\Siebel\myConfig.cfg /s D:\Siebel\sql-spool.txt`.

That way it will create a file with every SQL sentence being executed. This file will be quite big, so I suggest you to reproduce all the steps except the one causing trouble (open your Siebel client, navigate to the contacts screen, create a new record...), then open the SQL spool file in a text editor and position yourself at the end of the file. After that, click on the MVG field in Siebel, and refresh the spool file, to see what SQL sentences have been added.

The next step would be to launch the same sentences using a DB client (TOAD, Tora, SQL Plus...) and check if any of them takes too long to finish. You can access to the Oracle database administration console while doing so, and review the performance and the *execution plan* for each sentence, which can help you find what's causing the trouble. Most likely, you'll need to create an index for some columns.

If all the SQL sentences execute in a reasonable time, then you can discard the database and continue looking for problems in your SRF/repository:

- Do you have custom code in any business component or applet involved (contacts, addresses, etc.).
- Is your MVF field well defined? Is it vanilla or custom made?
- Are there user properties which apply to the MVG fields?

Try disabling any customisation you've made and check if it still happens with vanilla Siebel.

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving detailed explanation. It will definitely help. Thank You.